# Nginx log files to another process's stdin

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'd like to have a process that captures both access and error logs, without the logs being written to disk.  I'd like to use node.js `process.stdin` to the logs.  Any idea if nginx can be setup to stream the logs to another process instead of to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible, and there's a trac here: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/73

However, as in the comment to the trac, you could easily use pipe the logs from the file using `tail -F /path/to/access/log | your-node-script.js`. Please note that this will still write to disk and then read, so consider the IOPs usage.

Another option is to send Nginx's logs to a node application that acts as a syslog server. Doing that in Nginx is quite trivial (see: http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html ). You will then need to create a simple Node.js server that listens to port 514 UDP and processes the log. See an example in the highlighted lines here: https://github.com/cconstantine/syslog-node/blob/e243e2ae7ddc8ef9214ba3450a8808742e53d37b/server.js#L178-L200

Comment: Nice, using node as a syslog server sounds perfect.  Thanks!